# Basic regexp difference between bash and PowerShell

Tags: regex, bash, powershell

The following process in bash gives different result in PowerShell. First question: Is the regex interpretation different?
Second question: What should I do to get the results in bash using PowerShell?

Let's assume my directories:

```
0.0199
0.01991
0.01992
0.01993
```

**In bash:**

```
find . -name "0.019?*"

./0.01991
./0.01992
./0.01993
```

**In PowerShell:**

```
Child-Item -Recurse -Filter "0.019?*"

0.0199
0.01991
0.01992
0.01993
```

I don't want to see the file named "0.0199".

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://regex101.com/r/AnL4rw/1)? if not please show sample result

Comment: The -Filter parameter does not work with regex. If you need to use regex you have to use a Where-Object with -match.

Comment: `bash` doesn't use regexp there.  It's galled _globbing_.  A thing like `?*` doesn't make sense in regexp, but it does in globbing.  I don't know about Powershell, maybe it uses regexp.  The equivalent of the globbing `?*` would be regexp `..*`.

Comment: @MJNBelief Exactly like that.

Comment: @Olaf I think it doen't accept regex. So, my answer is below.

Comment: @Radioactive so, can you use that, where's wrong?

Comment: You are right @Olaf. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `bash` isn't actually involved here, because `0.019?*` is simply a string passed to `find`, which does the expansion. Is `Child-Item` a built-in command in PowerShell?

Comment: @chepner I mean shell scripting for bash when I say bash.  Yes, built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to second question with the help of @Olaf. -filter doesn't accept regex.

```
Child-Item 0.019?[1-9]
0.01991
0.01992
0.01993
```